# Rules "Add item to list" does not work with users

Tags: rules

I'm trying to add a user to a field with Rules. The rule has the following workflow:

- On Node Being Flagged
- Node is of Type
- Add Item To List

Item is the flagging user, and the list is a user reference field. This works with taxonomy terms, but not with usernames.

Do you have any idea?